# Vaadin Grid Prevent De-Selection

Tags: java, polymer, vaadin

I am using the vaadin grid to display data. I would like to disable the ability to de-select a row. I have found this similar question on stack overflow:

[How to select just one row, prevent to unselect item in singleselect mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424834/how-to-select-just-one-row-prevent-to-unselect-item-in-singleselect-mode)

This question suggests using the following code:

```
table.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
```

I am making my interface using Polymer 2x and HTML rather than java. How would I go about disabling de-selection in html and javascript.

Thanks in advance (sorry if this is a bit basic - fairly new to this)